# knockout view model properties undefined in onAfterRender function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a view model something like below, when onAfterRender is fired by Knockout then the function in the viewmodel (also called onAfterRender) is executed but the values for  this.gridColumns, this.gridOptions are undefined is there anyway to fix this? I would prefere to keep the object function rather than using an object literal.

I create my viewModel like this:

```
var model = new i2owater.viewmodels.AlarmsForViewModel(somedata);
```

and call ko.applyBindings(model);

this is my view model:

```
viewModel = function (serverData) {
var alarmGrid = {};

function onAfterRender() {
    var that = this;
    this.alarmGrid = new i2owater.Slickgrid();

    // this.gridColumns and this.gridOptions are both undefined
    this.alarmGrid.setupGrid("#alarmsGrid", [], this.gridColumns, this.gridOptions);
};

return {
    data: data,
    tabs: tabs,
    selectedPriority: selectedPriority,
    company: company,
    zone: zone,
    rows: rows,
    alarmPeriod: alarmPeriod,
    //alarmGrid: alarmGrid,
    gridColumns: [{ id: "id", name: "ID", field: "id", sortable: true },
        { id: "date", name: "Date", field: "date", sortable: true },
        { id: "description", name: "Description", field: "description"}],
    gridOptions: {
        editable: true,
        enableCellNavigation: true,
        asyncEditorLoading: true,
        forceFitColumns: false,
        topPanelHeight: 25,
        rowHeight: 40
    }
    onAfterRender: onAfterRender
};
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a several ways that you could ensure that `this` is correct in this situation.

One option would be to create a `result` variable, bind your function to that variable, then return `result`.

```
var result = {
    data: data,
    tabs: tabs,
    selectedPriority: selectedPriority,
    company: company,
    zone: zone,
    rows: rows,
    alarmPeriod: alarmPeriod,
    //alarmGrid: alarmGrid,
    gridColumns: [{ id: "id", name: "ID", field: "id", sortable: true },
        { id: "date", name: "Date", field: "date", sortable: true },
        { id: "description", name: "Description", field: "description"}],
    gridOptions: {
        editable: true,
        enableCellNavigation: true,
        asyncEditorLoading: true,
        forceFitColumns: false,
        topPanelHeight: 25,
        rowHeight: 40
    }
};

result.onAfterRender = onAfterRender.bind(result);

return result;
```

Otherwise, rather than returning an anonymous object literal, you can build it like this:

```
viewModel = function (serverData) {
    var alarmGrid = {};

    function onAfterRender() {
        var that = this;
        this.alarmGrid = new i2owater.Slickgrid();

        // this.gridColumns and this.gridOptions are both undefined
        this.alarmGrid.setupGrid("#alarmsGrid", [], this.gridColumns, this.gridOptions);
    };

    this.data = data;
    this.tabs = tabs;
    this.selectedPriority = selectedPriority;
    this.company = company;
    this.zone = zone;
    this.rows = rows;
    this.alarmPeriod = alarmPeriod;
    this.gridColumns = [{ id: "id", name: "ID", field: "id", sortable: true },
            { id: "date", name: "Date", field: "date", sortable: true },
            { id: "description", name: "Description", field: "description"}];
    this.gridOptions = {
        editable: true,
        enableCellNavigation: true,
        asyncEditorLoading: true,
        forceFitColumns: false,
        topPanelHeight: 25,
        rowHeight: 40
    };
    this.onAfterRender = onAfterRender.bind(this);
};
```

or use an extend function like in KO 1.3 `ko.utils.extend` to extend the current `this` like:

```
viewModel = function (serverData) {
    var alarmGrid = {};

    function onAfterRender() {
        this.alarmGrid = new i2owater.Slickgrid();
        this.alarmGrid.setupGrid("#alarmsGrid", [], this.gridColumns, this.gridOptions);
    };

    ko.utils.extend(this, {
        data: data,
        tabs: tabs,
        selectedPriority: selectedPriority,
        company: company,
        zone: zone,
        rows: rows,
        alarmPeriod: alarmPeriod,
        //alarmGrid: alarmGrid,
        gridColumns: [{ id: "id", name: "ID", field: "id", sortable: true },
            { id: "date", name: "Date", field: "date", sortable: true },
            { id: "description", name: "Description", field: "description"}],
        gridOptions: {
            editable: true,
            enableCellNavigation: true,
            asyncEditorLoading: true,
            forceFitColumns: false,
            topPanelHeight: 25,
            rowHeight: 40
        }
        onAfterRender: onAfterRender.bind(this)
    });
};
```

Also, an alternative to using `bind` would be to do a `var self = this;` at the beginning of the constructor function, then use `self` inside the onAfterRender function.

Comment: Not sure if i've missed something, how does that affect the  this.gridColumns being undefined?

Comment: Having looked at you examples I went back to the drawing board and found i could use onAfterRender(renderedNodesArray, bindingContext) the bindingContext allows me to access the gridOptions and gridColumns etc. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Oh yes, that is a good option, given that this type of function will be passed the bindingContext automatically.  For other functions, you would need to do one of the options above.  Can you close this one?